# How can I make accessing any data from a class throw an exception?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a class that represents a piece of hardware. I only want one thread to be able to control it at a time, but I also want to be able to kick another thread off the resource if it is taking too long. I think the best way to do this is keep track of the owner thread ID in the class, and throw an exception if any property whatsoever is accessed from another thread.

This appears to be a problem that can be solved with metaclasses - I need to somehow intercept attribute retrieval, and throw an exception if the thread ID is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a metaclass, you can use [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__):

```
class Hardware(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if super(Hardware, self).__getattribute__(owner_id) != current_thread_id:
            raise YourAccessError  # NOT AttributeError
        return super(Hardware, self).__getattribute__(attr)
```